# Process "\" in a string to "\\" for FilePath processing

Tags: c#, string, .net-4.5, filepath

I have a function in where I want to convert a string value `C:\samplec#programs\Converter` to `C:\\samplec#programs\\Converter` Note the differences. This is my function:

```
private string FilePathProcessor(string path)
{
    char[] oriCharArray = path.ToCharArray; 
    List<char> oriCharList = new List<char>;
    List<char> newCharList = new List<char>;
    foreach (char item in oriCharArray)
    {
        oriCharList.Add(item);
    }

    foreach (char items in oriCharList)
    {
        if ((items != "\\"))
        {
            newCharList.Add(items);
        }
        else
        {
            newCharList.Add(items);
            newCharList.Add(items);
        }
    }

    string result = string.Join(",", newCharList.ToArray());
    return result;
}
```

Of course this function serves my needs. But, I wonder if there is already an existing function in .Net which will take care of it. I am just cleaning up my code and checking for simpler and faster solution. Not going to reinvent the wheel if there is already a way.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Actually, I am placing this value into a mysql database. When I write it in the original form, it misses the "\". I have some hundreds of thousands of these values need to be processed before I could place it into my database table

Comment: Have you tried using SomeTypeOfWriteMethod(@"C:\sample#programs\Convertor");

Comment: No @programmerj. Didn't tried that

Comment: Use String.Replace()

Comment: As a note, don't think so specifically in your questions. This is a duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use String.Replace()

```
string path = @"C:\samplec#programs\Converter";
string output = path.Replace("\\", @"\\");
```

Comment: Thank you very much dude. I feel really stupid for not thinking about this

Comment: You do not have to feel stupid, for that we are, to help, luck